# find lines in one file but not in another file in Linux Shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have two files, one line is a string. I want to find lines in the first file, but not in the 2nd file. No matter what is the order (line number where the string exists). There are no duplicate lines inside one file. Wondering the shell command in Linux?

BTW, if there is a way to find common lines of the two files, it will be great as well. :)

For example,

file 1,

```
hello
world
python
java
scala
```

file 2,

```
hello
python
C++
C
Go
```

I want to output,

```
world
java
scala
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: is `diff` an option?

Comment: @ReutSharabani, good idea. But diff compare position (line by line compare), correct?

Comment: where does programming come into the picture?

Comment: @e4c5, shell programming. :)

Comment: @LinMa not if you use `sort` on both files before...

Comment: @ReutSharabani, could you show me how? Not quite catch. :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani, if you mean sort command on Linux, I think it is a bit tricky since I know sort treat number and string different?

Comment: @LinMa does it matter? if it's the same it's the same. You don't have a cross-line context. As long as you're using the same sort it's ok.

Comment: `sort` won't work if the number of lines in each file is different

Comment: @neverendingqs, thanks for the input, not quite catch your point, could you show an example?

Comment: @ReutSharabani, you mean using which option of sort? I want to try after your detailed guidance. :)

Comment: @neverendingqs why not? Doesn't diff try to compare more than just line by line? if the lines are ordered it will catch all differences won't it?

Comment: @ReutSharabani actually we'll run into problems even without changing the number of lines in either file. The example alone is a counter-example on why sorting first won't work.

Comment: @neverendingqs works for this pipe: `diff <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt) | grep "<" | cut -c3-`

Comment: @ReutSharabani I stand corrected - forgot `diff` takes care of that

Comment: @ReutSharabani, do not understand why in your command, you are using two "<" signs? I mean this part, "<(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)". Thanks.

Comment: This returns a file descriptor to the contents of the command.

Comment: @ReutSharabani, tried your command has issues, diff <(recom2.txt) < (recom3.txt) | grep "<" | cut -c3-, which reports error "-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('", any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
grep -f file.2 -v file.1
```

(It works for the example you give, but does not actually do what I interpret your question as asking, but the question is not clear so my interpretation may be completely wrong.)

Comment: thanks for the smart idea, which part in my question is not clear? I am happy to update.

Comment: This is great. Didn't know this is possible with files (`-v file` ...).

Comment: @LinMa, I think I'm just confused by your first sentence.  All lines in a file are strings!  You probably meant "each line contains exactly one word (no whitespace)."

Comment: @WilliamPursell, not one word, I should say ASCII English characters. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and here is how I solved it (for reference) :

```
sort file1 file2        | uniq -d > common_lines
sort file1 common_lines | uniq -u > file1_uniq_lines
```

or in oneline:

```
sort file1 <(sort file1 file2 | uniq -d) | uniq -u > file1_uniq_lines
```